# Highlight searched char/string in haystack and keep case

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

At the moment I have programmed an ajax search which is returning names. So far everything is working. However, I want to highlight the searched char/string simply with a `<strong>` tag but keep the case as I have got it from the SQL:

```
Example:
Search Term: M
SQL result: 1. Max Mustermann, 2. Tom Maier

What I want:
<b>M</b>ax <b>M</b>uster<b>m</b>ann
Tom <b>M</b>aier
```

Means, I wanna keep the case as I get it from the database, just put  tags around the char or string.

This is what I have so far, but it is not what I want. If I search a "m", the first char is also lower case although it is actually uppercase in the database.

```
public function highlightKeyword($haystack, $needle)
{
    $string = mb_strtolower($haystack);
    $string = $this->mb_ucfirst($string);
    $string = preg_replace("/(".$needle.")/i", sprintf("<strong>".strtolower($needle)."</strong>"), $string);
    return $string;
}

public function mb_ucfirst($string, $encoding)
{
    $strlen = mb_strlen($string, $encoding);
    $firstChar = mb_substr($string, 0, 1, $encoding);
    $then = mb_substr($string, 1, $strlen - 1, $encoding);
    return mb_strtoupper($firstChar, $encoding) . $then;
}
```

Any further ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_replace` with `/i` (case-insensitivity flag) and a capture group:

```
preg_replace('/('.preg_quote($needle).')/i', '<b>\1</b>', $haystack);
```

The `preg_quote` is there to escape any reserved characters that might occur in the needle.